# SQL : calculate multiple rows to result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How to get result table by calculate multirow?

```
Name     Type     Value
------------------------------
Name1    Plus     5000
Name1    Minus    1000
Name2    Plus     3000
Name2    Minus    2000
```

Desired result:

```
Name     Value(Plus-Minus) 
------------------------------
Name1    4000
Name2    1000
```

Comment: post your tryings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Plus' THEN Value
                WHEN Type = 'Minus' THEN - Value
                ELSE 0
           END) as total
FROM t
GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation, and take the difference of all "plus" values minus all "minus" values for each name group of records.

```
SELECT
    Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Plus' THEN [Value] ELSE 0 END) -
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Minus' THEN [Value] ELSE 0 END) AS diff
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Name;
```